# Show that the function $x \mapsto \dim(\mathrm{Im}(D_{x}f))$ is locally increasing and upper semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ of class $C^1$. Show that the function $x \mapsto \dim(\mathrm{Im}(D_{x}f))$ is locally increasing.

**Lemma.** *Let $M$ a matrix with rank $r$. Then there is $\delta>0$ such that $\Vert M - N \Vert < \delta$ implies $\mathrm{rank}(N) \geq r$.*

*Proof.* Obviously the result follows for $r = 0$. If $r > 0$, there is a $r \times r$ invertible submatrix $T$ in $M$. Since $T$ is invertible, $\det(T) \neq 0$. The determinant is a continuous function, so there is $\delta > 0$ such that for every $r \times r$ matrix $V$ with $\Vert T - V \Vert < \delta$ we have $\det(V) \neq 0$.

Here is my first question: If $N$ is a matrix with a submatrix $V$ that satisfies the previous description, so $\Vert T - V \Vert \leq \Vert M - N \Vert < \delta$ whenever $\Vert M - N \Vert < \delta$, that is, $\det(V) \neq 0$ then $\mathrm{rank}(N) \geq r$. But how can I ensure that a matrix $N$ with $\Vert M - N \Vert < \delta$ has such submatrix?

I think that this lemma solves the question, I dont write so, correct me if I'm wrong.

---

> Show that $x \mapsto \dim(Im(D_{x}f))$ is upper semicontinuous.

I dont know how to use the previous question to prove it. I have the definition:

A function is upper semicontinuous in $x_{0}$ if for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) < f(x_{0}) + \epsilon$ for any $x \in B_{\delta}(x_{0})$.

Comment: What is a locally increasing function with domain $\mathbb R^m$? And rank is lower semicontinuous, not upper semicontinuous (unless it's constant). Consider $f(x)=x^2$ with $n=m=1.$ Then $dim(Im(D_x f))$ is $1$ except at $0$ where it is $0.$

Comment: @Dap the range of rank function is in $\mathbb{R}$. I see, I can prove that rank is lower semicontinuous. Maybe its a error in the question.

Comment: @AlexRavsky, My problem is how ensure that the submatrix $V$ in $N$ exists. Probably its a dumb question. You can turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your first question. You didn’t specify the norm, but I guess that Lemma holds for any common norm on real-valued matrices, for instance, for $\ell^\infty$-norm, which concerns my following remarks.  Your proof of Lemma is correct and such a submatrix $T$ exists (see, for instance, subsection “Determinantal rank – size of largest non-vanishing minor” [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Alternative_definitions)). Then also exists 
respective $\delta>0$. Now if $\Vert M - N \Vert < \delta$ then a submatrix $V$ of $N$ *with the same indices of entries which has the matrix $T$ in $M$* (so $V$ exists because $T$ exists) satisfies $\Vert T - V \Vert \leq \Vert M - N \Vert < \delta$. Then $\det(V) \neq 0$ and $\mathrm{rank}(N) \geq r$.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!